# Custom Title Bar Can't Dragging in UWP App

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a custom Title Bar in my C# UWP Application. But the title bar doesn't drag.

My Custom Title Bar xaml code:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="DragRegion" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Loaded="DragRegion_Loaded"/>
```

Code for the DragRegion Loaded event:

```cs
private void DragRegion_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    CoreApplicationViewTitleBar coreTitleBar = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar;
    coreTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
    ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
    titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
    Window.Current.SetTitleBar(DragRegion);
}
```

I want to make title bar draggable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some little things you need to fix:

- make sure the VerticalAlignment is set to top
- make sure the HorizontalAlignment is set to Stretch
- make sure, that you define a height
- make sure to define a color so you can't click through the grid

Here the modified code:

```
  <Grid Height="30" Background="Transparent" x:Name="DragRegion" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Loaded="DragRegion_Loaded"/>
```

Here also the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/apps/develop/title-bar?tabs=winui2